# How to animate a MeshRenderer color in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity

I need to animate MeshRenderer.material.color.a, but fail.

Code:

```
    private void Method()
{
    AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip();
    AnimationClipPlayable playable = AnimationClipPlayable.Create(clip);

    AnimationCurve alpha = AnimationCurve.Linear(0, 1, 1, 0);
    clip.SetCurve("", typeof(MeshRenderer), "Material._Color.a", alpha);

    //gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red); // Works
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(playable); // Doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this using Unity 5.5.0f3, and the path for material alpha was the only problem. It should be "material._Color.a" (lower-case m). Otherwise, your code worked exactly as you wrote it.

I figured this out by creating an animation within the Unity editor, then examining the new .anim file in a text editor. I do this pretty often (read assets in a text editor) to find problems or to search for things for which Unity does not have a built-in tool. It's quite useful, and only requires that your project is set to save all assets as text.

Comment: How do you save assets as text? I'm curious

Comment: In Unity, go to Edit > Project Settings > Editor. In the Inspector, under "Asset Serialization", choose "Force Text". This will make some files larger than before, though I feel that the benefits are worth the extra storage space and network bandwidth for version control.